# Awk /sed extract information when a pattern match from a paragraph

Tags: awk, sed

I want to search a pattern "FROM" in paragraph that begins with CREATE VIEW and ends with ";" and save the result in a csv file. for example if I have the following file :

```
CREATE VIEW view1
AS something  
FROM table1 ,table2 as A, table3 (something FROM table4)  
FROM table5, table6
USING file1
;
CREATE VIEW view2 
FROM table1 ,table2 ,table6 ,table4
something 
something 
FROM table5 ,table7 (something FROM table4 ,table5(this is something FROM table8)
USING file2
;
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
view1;table1
view1;table2
view1;table3
view1;table4
view1;table5
view1;table6
view2;table1
view2;table2
view2;table6
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table7
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't pretended to know the syntax of whatever follows FROM in your input file so here's how to identify the view plus split the FROM lines at commas and you can take it from there:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"; OFS=";" }
sub(/^CREATE VIEW[[:space:]]+/,"") { view = $0 }
sub(/^FROM[[:space:]]+/,"") {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        print view, $i
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
view1;table1
view1;table2 as A
view1;table3 (something FROM table4)
view1;table5
view1;table6
view2;table1
view2;table2
view2;table6
view2;table4
view2;table5
view2;table7 (something FROM table4
view2;table5(this is something FROM table8)
```